# Printing part of binary sequence c++

Tags: c++, struct, io, binaryfiles

I've read from a binary file into some struct pointer. In my struct, there are several `unsigned int` integer. Here is my struct :

**EDIT**

```
   typedef unsigned int             INT32U;

typedef struct {
        INT32U var1 : 16;               
        INT32U var2 : 8;                       
        INT32U var3 : 1;                        
} myStruct;



typedef struct{
    myStruct  hdr;
    INT32U additionalVar;
}MyStructSecond;
```

And I read binary file with the following line:

```
    myStructSecond * pack;
FILE * stream = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
fread((INT32U*)pack->hdr,1,sizeof(myStruct),stream);
```

Now I want to access value of var1  but I dont know how could I do this?

Is there anyone to help me ? thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel like the `(INT32U*)` parameter is a typo, since that's a type, not a value.

Answer (score 1):

That's going to go horribly wrong - you've created a pointer, but no actual struct.

You want:

```
myStruct pack;
FILE * stream = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
ReadFile(stream, &pack, sizeof(pack));
```

And then you can access the values as e.g. `pack.var1`.

Comment: He did allocate a intance of the struct - right after the definition.

Comment: @Sam No. `myStruct` is a typedef; `pack` is a pointer.

Comment: @AlanStokes I've edited my post could you look at it again ?

Comment: Same problem. `myStructSecond * pack` declares a pointer, but it doesn't point at anything. You don't need a pointer anyway. Start with `myStructSecond pack` - just like I said above.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the problem is caused by use of a pointer in the call to `ReadFile` that has not been initialized properly.

I suggest

```
myStruct pack;
FILE * stream = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
ReadFile(stream, &pack, sizeof(myStruct));
```

**Update** In response to comment by OP.

```
myStructSecond pack;
FILE * stream = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
fread(stream, &pack.hdr, sizeof(myStruct));
```

Comment: @R_Sahu I've edited my question could you help me again ?

Comment: @R_Sahu, I guess something is wrong, it is not  working